# How to route to state in an angular function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do seems like it should be very simple.  I have done lots of research on the internet and cannot find anywhere that tells me how to do this.  All I want to do is route back to my main app page after a user submits a sign-up form.

This function triggers when I submit the add user form.

```
.controller('SignUpPageCtrl', [
'$scope',
'users',
function($scope, users){
$scope.signUpUser = function(){
users.create({
  username: $scope.username,
  password: $scope.password,
  email: $scope.email
});
$scope.username = '';
$scope.password = '';
$scope.email = '';
//I want to add a function right here that routes back to #/home
};
```

I want to route back to this /home state after that function creates a user for me.

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('home', {
  url: '/home',
  templateUrl: '/home.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl',
  resolve: {
    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
      return posts.getAll();
     }]
   }
  })
```

This is the template code from the html view

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
```

This seems like it should be extremely simple.  All I want to do is route back to the home state after the users.create function executes!

Comment: use `$state.go` method

Comment: do I have to pass $state as an argument into my SignUpPageCtrl controller?

Comment: yes, in correct terms, inject `$state` into the controller.